# Jquery Script clash between Google Maps, Lightbox & Anything Slider

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage with lightbox and anythingslider working but not Google maps, when I knock off lightbox & anythingslider, Google Maps works, help appreciated. 
http://www.schoolsacrossborders.org/testxxxyz/indextest.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the dollar sign in jquery use jQuery i.e.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: select it as the answer please.